# Showing that True Arithmetic ($TA$) is a maximal-consistent theory

Tags: logic, arithmetic, model-theory

> Let the language of arithmetic $\mathcal L^A$ denote the first-order
>   language with the function symbols $s$ (successor), $+$, and $\times$
>   and the constant $0$.
>
> Let $TA$ denote the set of sentences $\phi$ of $\mathcal L^A$ such
>   that $\mathbb N \models \phi$. (Here, $\mathbb N$ denotes the standard model of $Q$.)
>
> Finally, we say that a theory $\Sigma$ is maximal-consistent in
>   $\mathcal L^A$ if it's consistent and for any consistent theory
>   $\Theta$ such that $\Sigma \subseteq \Theta$, we have $\Sigma = \Theta$.

It's clear that $TA$ is consistent. However, although it seems obvious as well, I cannot produce a formal proof of the fact that $TA$ is maximal.

Could someone please show me how to do so?

Comment: Suppose $\Theta$ is as in the definition of maximal consistent: It is consistent, and it includes $TA$. If $\Theta$ contained a false statement $\psi$ about $\mathbb N$, then it would also contain $\neg\psi$ (because that's a true statement about $\mathbb N$, hence is in $TA$, and hence is in $\Theta$). That contradicts the assumption that $\Theta$ is consistent. So $\Theta$ contains only true statements about $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks, so simple! (And if you want to copy that exact response to an official answer, then I'll accept it.)